# How to fix Data and Cache file system error

Tags: twrp

Weird problem with my One Plus One. Cannot install ROM and Cannot repair file system via TWRP. I'm at my wits end. Can anyone help me fix this? The attached images should give you an idea of what I am talking about.

The system partition looks like this - [image: syspart]
However the data and cache partitions look like this - [image: data] and [image: cache]

When I try to format or repair using TWRP I get this - [image: error]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you installed any rom/is running any rom currently? is there any change after performing wipe all(internal, data, system, cache). Do a nandroid backup before that.

Comment: No ROM running currently. Was using Lineage. I hadnt used the phone for about 6 months. When I switched it ON, it went into bootloop. I decided to do a full wipe, which worked at first. Then I 'm not able to install ROM or Wipe the partitions. When performing a wipe, it shows the same error as shown in the picture. Basically an error with 'failed to mount data (Invalid Argument)'.

Comment: Go follow the instructions in the comments of this post: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-sp/help/format-data-using-twrp-3-0-2-t3371137